# How to automatically generate id in Fusion tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables

I am using Google Apps Script to do CRUD for my Fusion Table in Google Drive. I tried to find a way to let Fusion table handle my primary key which is just a number right now but no luck so far. Do I have to write code to generate key or is there a way to do automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be done automatically, the name of the column is `ROWID`.

Note: this column will not be returned when you use the asterisk as column_spec